# Typo3 Fluid detect Links in Text

Tags: hyperlink, textarea, typo3, fluid

This Code is showing a Textarea Input from the Backend in my Frontend:

```
<f:format.nl2br>{data.textfield}</f:format.nl2br>
```

Its possible there are Links in it as simple text for example:

```
http://www.example.com
```

Is it possible somehow to detect those links and wrap a linktag around it with Typo3 6 and Fluid?

Its rather easy in Javascript but if possible I prefer a Typo3/Fluid solution here.

Answer (score 0):

why dont you use the RTE for your Textfield in the Backend and render it in Fluid with

```
<f:format.html>{data.textfield}</f:format.html>
```

If you do it like this, you have your line breaks rendered and all the Links, too. You enable the RTE features in your TCA-Configuration:

```
'textarea' => array(
        'exclude' => 0,
        'label' => 'your_label_from_locallang.xlf',
        'config' => array(
                'type' => 'text',
                'cols' => 40,
                'rows' => 15
        ),
        'defaultExtras' => 'richtext[]'
    ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the fluid used in context of an extension? If so make the check on php side and bind a boolean value to the view. You can then use something like this:

```
<f:if condition="isLink">
    <f:then>
        <f:link.external uri="{data.textfield}" target="_blank">{data.textfield}</f:link.external>
    </f:then>
    <f:else>
        <f:format.nl2br>{data.textfield}</f:format.nl2br>
    </f:else>
</f:if>
```

Unfortunately condition is very limited in what it can check on fluid side only so this won't help if you can't use php.
Another possibility would be to create a ViewHelper for that.